npx react-native-asset not working for IOS
I am trying to link react native to my font folder, and I am getting only link to android. Output:
info Linking ttf assets to Android project 

For some reason I dont see the message for IOS and the font for IOS do not work to me.
this is react-native.config.js file:
module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {}, // grouped into "project"
    },
    assets: ['./src/fonts'], 
    };

Any suggestions?
